# 'Figure' object has no attribute 'vbar'

Tags: python-2.7, charts, jupyter, bokeh, attributeerror

This is my code, in python 2.7, supposed to display a bar chart using bokeh:

```
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral6
from bokeh.plotting import figure

output_file("Option Bundling.html")

options= ['Option 1', 'Option 2', 'Option 1+2']
counts = [df3.get_value(select.value, select.value), df3.get_value(select2.value, select2.value), df3.get_value(select.value,select2.value) ]

source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(options=options, counts=counts, color=Spectral6))

p = figure(x_range=options_list, y_range=(0,1), plot_height=250, title="Option Bundling",
       toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x='options', top='counts', width=0.9, color='color', legend="Options", source=source)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.legend.orientation = "horizontal"
p.legend.location = "top_center"

show(p)
```

When I try running it in Jupyter, the following message appears:

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-29-a4eb97059982> in <module>()
     14            toolbar_location=None, tools="")
     15 
---> 16 p.vbar(x='options', top='counts', width=0.9, color='color', legend="Options", source=source)
     17 
     18 p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None

AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'vbar'
```

The code comes from the bokeh documentation, I only changed variables. what can I change to make it run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`vbar` is a somewhat recent addition. The mostly likely explanation is that your installed version of Bokeh is to old, and you will need to upgrade to be able to use `vbar`. If you can't upgrage for some reason, `quad` and `rect` will be available.